# Proving two versions of Pasch's Axiom are equivalent

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, axioms

I am trying to show that these two versions of Pasch's axiom are the same.

A1. If a line enters a triangle at a vertex, then the line intersects the opposite side.

A2. If a line enters a triangle at a side without intersecting the opposite vertex, then the line intersects one of the other two sides.

But, I can figure out how to use either axiom for proving the other axiom.

Comment: You asked [this question before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3984499/409). Deleting-and-reposting is not the appropriate way to attract more attentiont; rather, you should edit that version of the question to improve its quality. (Addressing the comments about what axioms are known would help. When dealing with the most-fundamental of results in geometry, it's important to be very clear about what we can and can't assume. The author of the source of the given exercise may have presented material in an uncommon way in order to suit an educational agenda.)

Comment: What @Blue said.

Comment: I guess, based on what we covered in class we can use the first four postulates of Euclid and Playfair's axiom.

Comment: We've talked about the fifth parallel postulate, but I am not sure how I can use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just do one direction. Assume A1, we work to show A2. Let $ABC$ be a triangle, and assume we have a line $l$ entering triangle $ABC$ at side $AB$ (without loss of generality) at a point $D$ on $AB$ and not intersecting $C$. Then $l$ enters either triangle $DAC$ or $DBC$ at vertex $D$, and then apply A1 to whichever the case is (e.g. if $l$ enters $DAC$ then A1 says it intersects $AC$.

Comment: Got it, I figured the other one out, as well! Thanks!!